# Proprietary BCM wireless driver ceased to work

Tags: wireless, inspiron

Suddenly, the propriety Broadcom STA wireless driver ceased to work on my Inspiron 1525 Dell. All of a sudden, when I turned on the laptop the tooltip of the wireless indicator in the top panel shows `networking disabled`.

This also cause the wired network interface not to work, unless I manually `dhclient` it.

Indeed, `lsmod` doesn't show anything with `bcm` in it.

How can I further troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the file `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state`. Very likely the attribute `NetworkingEnabled`  or `WirelessEnabled` is set to false.

Make sure the two lines show

```
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
```

save the file and the restart the network-manager daemon with

```
sudo stop network-manager
sudo start network-manager
```

After this your network should come up again.

Comment: How could that happen? I didn't do anything with sudo at all. Moreover, after I suspended and got back from suspending it suddenly began to work. I really hate this kind of weird problems.

Comment: Yeah. sometimes that happens particularly when the computer crashes, or in conjunction with sleeping when it crashes from that state. If we would know exactly the details, we probably would have fixed it already. Otherwise, please use this workaround, and hopefully we will find the source and remove the problem in its entirety.

Comment: what you should do is, detect that the networking is not enabled, and add to the networking menu option to "Renew NetworkManager", in case it is off. Thanks.

Comment: it happens after I return from hibernate, and it for some reason fails to return from hibernate. I'll try to report a bug once details are clear...